# How to record a video of computer screen movements

Tags: video, screen-casting

Can someone suggest good softwares for making a video tutorial of computer screen, like is done on most computer tutoring sites?

I am looking a software that can capture a video of my blackberry simulator run so that the client can preview the look and feel of an app on the device.

Please suggest software that is freely available and which doesn't add any watermarks.

Comment: are you running windows or OSX? Free or paid?

Comment: Windows XP Professional registered version

Comment: It's called a "screencast"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a large number of these, mostly advertised on gaming websites, but I think this question may be too localised.

Google will find you many, 2 seconds found me this:

http://www.anewmorning.com/2009/01/06/5-free-alternatives-to-fraps/

And if you want to find a good one, that link gives some information about each one.

Comment: Thanks.Well yes i have googled too.I wanted some experienced users to suggest their opinions in case they are themselves using one.

Comment: I used to use Fraps, but find the performance of WeGame is easily sufficient for my COD/MW antics, and is free.

Comment: I just tried Cam studio and its working great.

Comment: @techie If you can find them on Google but you are looking for the opinions of experienced people, just make sure to say that in your question :)

Answer (score 4):

I love using Camstudio!
It's free I've used it , not the best interface but great to use until you are willing to pony up $300 for Camtasia.

http://camstudio.org/

Comment: Yeah absolutely.But i am yet to figure out how can i go about editing the videos.Atleast the free version doesnt support this feature it looks.

Comment: Use CamSTudio to make your raw videos then something like iMovie or Windows Movie maker to edit the pieces together.

Answer (score 0):

I use Open Broadcaster Software for that purpose. It is well known for its streaming capability but can also record the screen with high quality and flexibility.

https://obsproject.com/